# Off-shell Photons and Collinear Divergences

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, research-level, infrared-radiation

I am reading Weinberg's book "The Quantum Theory of Fields", vol. 1. Weinberg suggests that the effect of radiative corrections involving $N$ soft photons is to multiply the (non-radiative) matrix element $M_{\beta\alpha}$ for the process without such radiative corrections by a factor
$$\frac{1}{N!2^N}\bigg[\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4}\sum_{mn}e_ne_m\eta_n\eta_mJ_{nm}\bigg]^N$$
where
$$J_{nm}=-i(p_n\cdot p_m)\int_{\lambda\le|\textbf{q}|\le\Lambda}
\frac{d^4q}{(q^2-i\epsilon)(p_n\cdot q-i\eta_n\epsilon)(p_m\cdot q-i\eta_m\epsilon)}$$

My question has nothing to do with divergences due to taking the $\lambda$ cutoff to be zero, but rather, with divergences that arise in the case in which the interacting fermions in both the initial and the final states are massless. Next, the author claims that summing over $N$ yields the famous exponentiation property of virtual soft photons, and after doing so, he tries to evaluate $J_{nm}$.

Evaluating $J_{nm}$ implies performing the contour integral with respect to $q^0$, which yields
$$J_{nm}=-(p_n\cdot p_m)\int_{\lambda\le|\textbf{q}|\le\Lambda}
\frac{d^3q}{\textbf{q}^3(E_n-\textbf{p}_n\cdot \hat{\textbf{q}})
(E_m-\textbf{p}_m\cdot \hat{\textbf{q}})},\hspace{1em} \eta_n=-\eta_m=\pm1
\\
J_{nm}=-(p_n\cdot p_m)\int_{\lambda\le|\textbf{q}|\le\Lambda}
\frac{d^3q}{\textbf{q}^3(E_n-\textbf{p}_n\cdot \hat{\textbf{q}})
(E_m-\textbf{p}_m\cdot \hat{\textbf{q}})}-\frac{4i\pi^3}{\beta_{nm}},\hspace{1em} \eta_n=\eta_m=\pm1$$

This is as far as the book goes. The rest are my considerations. Assume that there is an initial and a final massless interacting fermions. Then, one can write
$$J_{nm}\sim(1-\cos\psi)\int_{\lambda\le|\textbf{q}|\le\Lambda}
\frac{d^3q}{\textbf{q}^3(1-\hat{\textbf{p}}_n\cdot \hat{\textbf{q}})
(1-\hat{\textbf{p}}_m\cdot \hat{\textbf{q}})}
\\
\sim(1-\cos\psi)\log\Big(\frac{\Lambda}{\lambda}\Big)
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}
\frac{\sin\theta d\theta d\phi}{(1-\cos\theta)
(1-\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\psi\cos\theta)}$$
where I have chosen $p_n=(E,0,0,E)$ and $p_m=(E,E\sin\psi,0,E\cos\psi)$ and finally $\hat{\textbf{q}}=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)$.

**My questions are the following:**

1. The additional virtual photon here is off-shell. But in completing the contour we identified (in some cases) $q^0=\pm(|\textbf{q}|-i\epsilon)$. Does that mean that the virtual photon is **on-shell** now?
2. According to my understanding (if I am not mistaken in my derivation), there will be collinear divergences among the contributions from the virtual soft photons, besides the divergences associated with the limit $\lambda\rightarrow0$. Is this true?
3. All the possible poles are
   $$q^0=|\textbf{q}|-i\epsilon,\hspace{1em}q^0=-|\textbf{q}|+i\epsilon
   \\
   q^0=\textbf{v}_n\cdot\textbf{q}-i\eta_n\epsilon,\hspace{1em}
   q^0=\textbf{v}_m\cdot\textbf{q}-i\eta_m\epsilon$$
   Where did all the $i\epsilon$ factors go into Weinberg's result for $J_{nm}$?

Any help will be appreciated..